# Why it is unsafe to run applications as root in Docker container?

Tags: linux, security, docker

There are many sources telling it is bad to run apps under root inside Docker container but they always refer to this link: https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/docker-container-breakout-proof-of-concept-exploit/ with issue fixed long ago because newer Docker versions whitelist kernel capabilities.

Therefore:

- Were there any other Docker exploits that worked under container root user but didn't work under container non-root user?
- Were there any linux kernel exploits that worked under container root user but didn't work under container non-root user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combat image misuse. Running applications as non-privileged user helps keeping system secure when image users misuse Docker - e.g. run with `--privileged` or mount system directories into container.

Answer (score 5):

So, this is skirting the question a little bit but I'm going to try my best to give you an informative and in-depth answer to help you understand the issues involved with running an application as root.

First off, this isn't a 100% definite no-go. You *can* run applications as root, and in some cases you may need to. But in software, we have something known as the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), also known as the Principle of Least Authority in some areas. This is an important concept in computer security, promoting minimal privileges on computers, based on users' job necessities. Each system component or process should have the least authority necessary to perform its duties. This helps reduce the "attack surface" of the computer by eliminating unnecessary privileges that can result in network exploits and computer compromises. You can apply this principle to the computers you work on by ordinarily operating without administrative rights.

By unnecessarily running an application as root is giving the program permissions to do things that it does not need to do - such as perform system functions and to manage a variety of the operating system's configuration settings. If your application is a basic website filled with cooking recipes, it does not need access to the system configuration files.

Applications are meant to be run with non-administrative security (or as mere mortals) so you have to elevate their privileges to modify the underlying system. This is how the general security model has worked for years.

It also makes applications easier to deploy and adds a layer of scalability. In general, the fewer privileges an application requires the easier it is to deploy within a larger environment. Applications that install device drivers or require elevated security privileges typically have additional steps involved in their deployment. For example, on Windows a solution with no device drivers can be run directly with no installation, while device drivers must be installed separately using the Windows installer service in order to grant the driver elevated privileges.

I apologise if this does not answer your question, but I've done my best to explain why you should not run applications as root. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Running dockerized apps under non-root user is a MAJOR hassle and, while using non-root is definitely more secure, I'm hoping to find out specific reasons to do not use root.